# Powershell listing size of files

Tags: powershell

I have 3600 files named PKA.dump

One of these files is not the right size. They should be above 500bytes, but one is below 500. Is there a way to check all subsubfolders and find the one file named PKA.dump that is less than 500 bytes?

Sorry I meant to add I am using powershell.

I had it working in linux, but powershell is so new to me

Comment: What commands have you tried, and with what results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do:

```
Get-Childitem -path C:\yourpath\ -Include pka.dump -recurse | where {$_.Length -le 500}
```

After reading the comments i did some performance testing and indeed using the `-include` parameter saves (in my test case) about 15% execution time per call on average so if performance is a major concern don´t use `-Filter` when using `-Recurse`

Comment: This just brings up a new >> prompt.

Comment: @jack then you didnt copy the closing bracket

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Get-ChildItem -Filter pka.dump -Recurse`?

Comment: Actually change '-Filter' to '-Include'.  So, `Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\yourpath\' -Include 'pka.dmp' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Length -le 500}` or change to the path and do `gci 'pka.dmp' -r | ?{$_.Length -le 500}`

Answer (score 1):

*update*

After hasing it out, best answer seems to be:
`Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\yourpath\' -Include 'pka.dmp' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Length -le 500}`

---

*original answer*

`gci -r | sort Length | select -First 10`

This should list all files, pipe it to sort by size (default ascending) and select the first 10

---

`Get-Help`, `Get-Command`, `Get-Member` are your friends.

Don't forget to upvote and mark answers.

Comment: but it just needs to be PKA.dump files

Comment: gci -path "$RootDirectoryGoesHere" -r | ?{($_.Length -le 500) -and ($_.Name -eq "PKA.dmp")}

Comment: @Trey 's comment would work, but `gci -path "$RootDirectoryGoesHere" -Include "PKA.dmp" -r | ? {$_.Length -le 500}` would be better.  -Include would filter at the start, reducing the stream that moves though pipe.  Piping to sort and select can allow more flexibility.

Comment: Why would you want to sort thousands of files when you can just get the one which is less than 500 bytes long? How is that "better" or "more flexibile"?

Comment: Good point, @BillWoodger.  I would use the last one I listed.  I'd keep sort and select in my pocket for the next time though.  What if his criteria is 10 biggest resource hogs, or whatever.  Oh and Paul's answer above is best answer.

Comment: If you update, there may be a vote in it (plus we can tidy up the comments).